# Magento 2.2.3 + PHP 7.1.32 results in "Function mcrypt_module_close() is deprecated" error

Tags: magento2, mcrypt

I am running **Magento 2.2.3** together with **PHP 7.1.32**. The M2E Pro extension throws the **Function mcrypt_module_close() is deprecated** error.

I tried adding `@` in front of any mcrypt calls, did not work. The strange thing is, it complains about line 112 in `vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Crypt.php` but the line has the `@` in front of the call, like this:

```
 @mcrypt_module_close($this->_handle);
```

So any idea what I might try?

Comment: Try to run composer update command and see are you getting same issue or not.

Comment: So you want me to update the Magento version?

Comment: No just run composer update command and see it is working fine or not.

Comment: What would be the result of running that command? Wouldnt it update something?

Comment: @Arnie: i also faced exact the similar issue. this is PHP version issue. Upgrade your php version in 7.2 or 7.2+. or you can install mcrypt for your current php version.